# VBA Stuck after certain loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code in excel VBA but am stuck at one point where i need help from you experts please. File is attached

The scenario is this that i have a data where column D has shipment # and when i receive it i put yes in column E. I need to prepare a report where in column E there is blank then if there is blank in column E then copy the shipment number of that blank from column D and paste it in column J which i have already done coding. but now i am stuck as I need to copy the name also which is in column B with same criteria. meaning that for the same shipment number which is copied in column J the name from column B should be copied and pasted in column K by finding the shipment number in column D and then selecting the name from column B for that shipment number.

Image is the data I have

[image: Image is the data i have]

Code:

[image: Code]

Comment: Please read [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [edit] your question to add your code formatted as code block. Also include which error you get and in which line, or where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Sub CopyData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim D As Range
For Each D In Range("D2:D500")
If D.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
D.Copy
Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next D

Comment: Please [edit] your original question. Don't post code in comments, it is not readable.

Comment: Sub CopyData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim D As Range
For Each D In Range("D2:D500")
If D.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
D.Copy
Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next D
End Sub    "this code which i have written it finds the blank cells in column E & then copies cells from column D adjacent left to it. I used offset to copy those cells in column D. but now with the same criteria i want to copy column B but how to proceed an not getting it.Just like column D i want column B also with same criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the below code , This is working fine at my end.

```
Sub so()
lRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
lRow1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=""
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy       Range("J1")
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & lRow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("K1")
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub CopyData() Application.ScreenUpdating = False Dim D As Range For Each D In Range("D2:D500") If D.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then D.Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) Application.CutCopyMode = False End If Next D End Sub "this code which i have written it finds the blank cells in column E & then copies cells from column D adjacent left to it. I used offset to copy those cells in column D. but now with the same criteria i want to copy column B but how to proceed an not getting it.Just like column D i want column B also with same criteria.